# Nethereum: Miner start takes time

Tags: miner, nethereum

I have set up a private ethereum block chain and I have created a .net application that uses nethereum to interface with the geth node.
After submitting a transaction I try to start the miner by using

var miningResult = await web3.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync(6);
 var receipt = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionReceipt.SendRequestAsync(transactionHash);

But sometimes the mining takes a long time to start. I checked on the windows task manager and found that geth.exe remains dormant even after Miner.Start command. after a minute or so it starts mining.
What causes the delay ?

Comment: Bump. anyone ??